# Why does mat-tab-nav-bar need 2 clicks to load router content?

Tags: angular, mat-tab

I'am using the `mat-tab-nav-bar` to implement the angular **mat-tab** feature with links to routers.

**xxx.component.html**:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
        <a *ngFor="let link of navLinks" mat-tab-link
          #rla="routerLinkActive"
          [active]="isViewInitialized && isLinkActive(rla)"
          [routerLink]="link.path"
          routerLinkActive>
          {{link.label}}
        </a>
</nav>
```

**xxx.component.ts**:

```
navLinks = [];
```

The issue is that when I load the component where the `mat-tab-nav-bar` is embedded, the app doesn't load the whole content of the first tab. It loads just the header which is static. The rest which is dynamically generated (http call to a database), doesn't show up. I need to click once again on the tab to load the content. in other words I have to click 2 times. And some times, I just need to click once more somewhere in the document body, to load the content.

But When I use the default `mat-tab` tag, I can get the content immediately when I navigate to the component.

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onLinkClick($event)">
        <mat-tab label="org">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Create">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Update">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

This fix the issue, but in the other hand, I can't use a routerlink for this option.

The component where the `mat-tab` feature if impelemented, does belongs to custom module with router using children:

```
export const CustomModuleRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'org', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: '', component: CustomComponent, canActivate: [ AuthguardGuard ],

    children: [
        { path: 'org', component: OrgComponent, data: { label: 'Overview' } },
        { path: '',  redirectTo: 'org', pathMatch: 'full'},

        { path: 'create', component: CreateComponent, data: { label: 'CREATE' } },
        { path: 'delete', component: DeleteComponent, data: { label: 'DELETE' } },
    ]
},
```

];

Any hint how to come around this issue? I don't mind which option would solve the issue. The `mat-tab-nav-bar` or `<mat-tab-group><mat-tab...`

Comment: Why cant the whole data be loaded by making `http` call ? I am not able to understand your scenario. Why cant you load `navLinks` when the app is loaded ?

Comment: The http call to backend in the component works fine. The issue is that the xxx.component.html doesn't show the whole content immediately when navigating to it. Let's say I'am in: http://localhost:4200/home and when I navigate to: http://localhost:4200/home/org, I can see the 3 tabs and they are linked, the first tab is active, but there just a headline and the rest is not loaded. I have to click once more on `org` tab to load the whole content. Or just click somewhere on the document body.

Comment: Would you mind creating a demo code on stackblitz.com ? Something is wrong with the sequence you are calling the data. A demo would help me understand where can we fix it

Comment: Sure. Just have to mention that the component, where I' am using mat-tab feature belongs to a custom/own module imported in the root app.module.

Comment: Hi. I am facing the same problem @k.vincent any solution found?